# Use JavaScript to return correct row number without using inline code

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, row-number, inline-code

Is there a way of using javascript to alert the correct row number, without using "onclick" or "this"  or in fact any javascript in the HTML other than a link to a js page?

This is my HTML

```
<div align='center'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Row Number  </b></td>
            <td>Confirm</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class='row_num'>100</td>
            <td><button class='confirmed'>Confirm</button></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class='row_num'>101</td>
            <td><button class='confirmed'>Confirm</button></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class='row_num'>102</td>
            <td><button class='confirmed'>Confirm</button></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class='row_num'>103</td>
            <td><button class='confirmed'>Confirm</button></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class='row_num'>104</td>
            <td><button class='confirmed'>Confirm</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="js/test.js"></script>
```

and here's the javascript. Now I am aware that the code is wrong and why it's wrong. I'm using a for loop that returns every row number. So I put a break in but, this just breaks at the first-row number and alerts 100 on every button. So what I need to know is if it's possible to alert the correct row number without using any inline javascript code in HTML page.

```
window.onload = addListener();

function buttonClick(){

var x = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");

var rowNum = document.getElementsByClassName("row_num");

if (x)
var y;
for (y = 0; y < rowNum.length; y++) {
var nums = rowNum[y].innerText;
    alert(nums + " Has been deleted");
        break;
}
else
return false;
}

function addListener() {
var i;
var z = document.getElementsByClassName("confirmed");
for (i = 0; i < z.length; ++i){
z[i].addEventListener("click", buttonClick);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your console. `else` after `for` is invalid syntax.

Try to use `.textContent` (the standard property name) rather than `.innerText`, which is something old and nonstandard introduced by IE.

You're on the right track, though I would suggest using the array functions rather than `for` loops, especially since you're using `var` which has hoisting issues.

```js
window.onload = addListener();

function buttonClick(e) {
  if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")) return;
  const tr = e.target.closest('tr');
  const rowNum = tr.children[0].textContent;
  alert(rowNum + " Has been deleted");
}

function addListener() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.confirmed').forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener("click", buttonClick);
  });
}
```

```html
<div align='center'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Row Number  </b></td>
            <td>Confirm</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class='row_num'>100</td>
            <td><button class='confirmed'>Confirm</button></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class='row_num'>101</td>
            <td><button class='confirmed'>Confirm</button></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class='row_num'>102</td>
            <td><button class='confirmed'>Confirm</button></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class='row_num'>103</td>
            <td><button class='confirmed'>Confirm</button></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class='row_num'>104</td>
            <td><button class='confirmed'>Confirm</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank so much, your code worked. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You better attach eventListener to the whole table and then operate with a 'target' attribute on event. This way you can access a particular element in the table and extract its html(or innerText) that will indicate the row number in this scenario.